# Locating Columns that Contain a String in their Name

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

Other than manually traversing every table schema in the entire database, how can I produce a list of all tables that contain a field containing the string "email" in [Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/)?

For example, in IBM DB2, I can do this with a query like this:

```
select tabschema,tabname,colname
from syscat.columns
where upper(colname) LIKE UPPER('%email%')
order by tabname
```

How can I achieve this in Pervasive 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [System Objects](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlsystb.htm), use:

```
SELECT f.Xf$Name, g.Xe$Name
FROM X$File f
INNER JOIN X$Field g ON g.Xe$File = f.Xf$Id
WHERE UPPER(g.Xe$Name) LIKE '%EMAIL%';
```

Comment: Fantastic! How did you discover this? Works great!

Comment: The company I worked for used a Pervasive 7 database, and after that seen different version up to 13.   The docs, i linked to, contain many thing which can help if the syntax in Pervasive/Actian is slightly different from other DBMS'es.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still open to other suggestions, but the way I did this was by exporting the database schema to a `.sql` text file, and I used a regular expression `create table.*email` to search through that file and locate all the tables containing a column with `email` in their name.

This worked, but I look forward to other people's suggestions.